# Trouble updating an interface using declaration merging

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I'm having difficulty using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) on an interface exported from a library I've made.

*A stackblitz example of the problem can be seen here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qxvrte (stackblitz appears to have spotty support for declaration merging, but I'm also having trouble in my local dev setup).*

In general, my setup is like so:

```js
// file_a.ts

declare module '@rschedule/core' {
  interface DateAdapterType {
    one: string;
  }
}
```

```js
// file_b.ts

import { DateAdapterType } from '@rschedule/core';
import './file_a';

function test(date: DateAdapterType) {
  date.base; // should be type `DateAdapterBase`
  date.one; // should be type `string`
}
```

I'm finding that my local type declaration in `file_a` is overwriting the type of `DateAdapterType` rather than being merged with it (so, in the example above, `date` has the form `{ one: string }` when it should have the form `{ base: DateAdapterBase; one: string }`.

Am I missing something with how declaration merging works?

Source code for `@rschedule/core` can be seen [here](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule/blob/fa4a6f1b9e7f4df2312d8f268643b67559fedd78/packages/core/core/date-adapter.ts#L3). The distributed npm code can be seen [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/@rschedule/core@0.11.7-next.26/).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

#### PS

I've noticed that if I update `@rschedule/core` so that the `DateAdapterType` is declared as a global type (i.e. `declare global { interface DateAdapterType ... }`), then declaration merging works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As [helpfully suggested in the typescript gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5d76825b50508949d305692c), the issue is that, for interface declaration merging to work, all declarations after the first need to specify the exact *file* which the interface was originally declared in. In the problem code above, `@rschedule/core` is merely reexporting the declaration from `@rschedule/core/es2015/packages/core/core/date-adapter`.

So the working code:

```js
// file_a.ts

declare module '@rschedule/core/es2015/packages/core/core/date-adapter' {
  interface DateAdapterType {
    one: string;
  }
}
```

This limitation of typescript does not appear to be mentioned anywhere official. I've gone ahead and created a request to update the typescript documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33326.